# How to find file paths in text?

Tags: c#

**Situation:**
I have some html code with a lot of linux file paths (/home/lol/test for example)

it needs to be done in C# with php and html files how?

Comment: `/` has a syntactical meaning in HTML, am I wrong? Unless the `/`s are escaped then it is not HTML code. Show us some of what you have and explain what you want to get to?

Comment: @Jodrell, `am I wrong?` probably.

Comment: @L.B I think I am, probably, unless the `/`s are inside the tags.

Comment: define('DIR_FS_SQL_CACHE', '/home/ca***ot/public_html/cache');

Like those.. would htmlagilitypack do that? Any code example? Ooooops... in php code

Comment: "Filter" as in remove or as in list file/line of occurrence? In PHP *and* HTML? Are you opposed to blind string replacement? It wouldn't catch semantic paths though (like `base + "/path/to/file"`).

Comment: Simply find all paths.. none specific just all the paths.. and return them in a string array..

Comment: Use PHP's `get_file_contents` function to read the HTML into a PHP variable, then use a regex to find all occurrences of the string. I'm not good enough with regular expressions to figure that out, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Travesty3, you clearly didn't read the question. This needs to be done in C#... I already have the php/html files

Comment: @SwenKooij: Clearly, you edited the question to say C# **after** I posted my comment.

Comment: @Travesty3, to make it more clear but if you had seen the tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a Parser class to read all the text and split it to parts that you like to get from it.

If you post some part of your HTML it will be more easy to help you out.

You can get the HTML as a string with the following:

```
    private string GetWebPage()
    {
        string pageSource;
        string getUrl = "http://index.htm";
        WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sourceResult = pageSource;
        }
        return sourceResult;
    }
```

And after that you can split it to parts that you like to get out of it.

```
char[] trimChars = new char[] { ' ', ':', '/', '\\', '.' };
string[] split = sourceResult.Split(trimChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can follow --

1. Get a HttpWebResponse for your page url
2. Read the response in a Stream
3. Fill a StreamReader with this Stream
4. Read entire page content from this StreamReader to a StringBuilder
5. Use Regex pattern to find file path from above stingbuilder or if that file path is within a attribute then get the index for that attribute from the stringbuilder and then retrieve the file path. Once get the 1st file path then substring remaining string and follow same index way to get next one.

Hope this will help you.